# Reduce import cost of TSDX package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, performance, rollupjs, tsdx

So I'm a bit new to bundle size performance improvements and something I'm trying to do is to reduce the import cost of my component library that's written in [TSDX](https://tsdx.io/). It's a tool to create Typescript libraries based on rollup.js. I'm using the out of the box setup.

When I investigated my app I found out that the import cost of components from my component library seems to be a lot. See images:

[image]

[image]

It seems that when I import a single component (or function) there is a lot of other things imported as well. Is there someone out there that knows if this is normal and/or if I can improve this? Maybe someone knows how I can import it like how they do it with the lodash packages where you import a single util from a specific folder like so: `import { add } from 'lodash/add'`?

So long story short: how can I reduce the import cost of my TSDX (based on rollup.js) library? Thanks in advance!

Comment: any update on this ?

Comment: @BryanLumbantobing I don't have any update, but I moved away from this and I'm using a custom setup with esbuild now.

Comment: Would you mind sharing references about how you setup it with esbuild?